# Comment dit-on « happy anniversary » en français ? — What is “happy anniversary” in French?

Tags: traduction

Quel est l'équivalent français de « happy anniversary » ? « Happy anniversary » s'utilise en anglais pour un évènement autre qu'un anniversaire de naissance.

Comment: FLE n'est pas un site de traduction. Ce site http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais?query=happy+anniversary&source=english résoudra vos problèmes de traduction et celui-là aussi : http://www.reverso.net/translationresults.aspx?lang=FR&direction=anglais-francais quoique que l'on  traduise *happy* par *joyeux* pour les évènements festifs.

Comment: [Reverso](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/anniversary) is also a good tool. If you can't find what you want there say so and we'll help, but thjis is not a translation site. You must propose something and say why you need more information.

Comment: @cl-r, Laure: Je ne comprends pas vos réactions. C'est particulierement difficile de trouver la bonne réponse. Encore plus difficile d'être certain qu'on a trouvé la bonne.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez La question dont nous avons demandé la fermeture était "Comment dit-on " happy anniversary" en français". Il n'y avait aucune indication d'une moindre recherche, si on de mande de l'aide pour trouver un mot en français la moindre des choses serait de montrer qu'on a cherché et pas trouvé. La question a été éditée depuis. Et pas par celui qui l'a posé.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez  Il serait préférable que ceux qui sont invités à modifier leurs questions le fasse eux-mêmes, c'est certainement dans l'intérêt du site. Et quand ils ont commencé à préciser on peut les aider par d'autres questions. C'est pour ça que je maintiens ma demande de fermeture, si on veut de meilleures questions il faut aussi aider les gens à les poser ; comme « Quand un homme a faim, mieux vaut lui apprendre à pêcher que de lui donner un poisson »

Answer (score 4):

Il faut préciser de quel anniversaire il s'agit comme par exemple « **Joyeux anniversaire de mariage** ». « Joyeux anniversaire » sans autre précision correspond à « *Happy birthday*  ».

---

You should state what anniversary it is about, something like "***Joyeux anniversaire de mariage***." "*Joyeux anniversaire*" alone is "Happy birthday."